# Validate textbox in c# with wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, styles

I have a window with some textboxes, comboxes and checkboxes. One of the textboxes need to be a number so I wanted to validate it. I searched through the internet and found a good [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation). I tried to use it, but it seems that it doesn't work or I did something wrong and I just don't see what I did wrong. So I hope anyone here can say me what I'm doing wrong or an other solution to get it started. 
Here is the xaml of the window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.mainpanels.EditWorkAssignments"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:validators="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.validationRules"
    Title="EditWorkAssignments" Height="225" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                   Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Datum:"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Projekt:"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="Ist Passiv:"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Content="Dauer:"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Content="Mitarbeiter:"/>
    <DatePicker Name="datePicker" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="3" />
    <ComboBox Name="comboBoxProject" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" />
    <CheckBox Name="checkBoxIsPassiv" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="3" />
    <TextBox Name="textBoxDauer" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="3" >
        <Binding Path="workAssignment.duration" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <validators:IsNumberValidationRule ErrorMessage="Dauer has to be a number." />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox>
        <ComboBox Name="comboBoxEmployee" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Margin="3">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                            <Binding Path="firstname"/>
                            <Binding Path="surname"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        MinWidth="80" Margin="3" Content="Save"  Click="saveHandler"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
        MinWidth="80" Margin="3" Content="Cancel" Click="cancelHandler" />
</Grid>
```

the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1.mainpanels
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for EditWorkAssignments.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class EditWorkAssignments : Window
    {
        EmployeeManagementEntities1 context = null;
        public WorkAssignement workAssignment;

        public EditWorkAssignments(WorkAssignement workAssignment)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.workAssignment = workAssignment;

            context = new EmployeeManagementEntities1();
            DbSet<Employee> employeeDb = context.Set<Employee>();
            employeeDb.Load();
            comboBoxEmployee.ItemsSource = employeeDb.Local;

            DbSet<Project> projectDb = context.Set<Project>();
            projectDb.Load();
            comboBoxProject.ItemsSource = projectDb.Local;
            comboBoxProject.DisplayMemberPath = "projectname";
        }


        private void saveHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Employee employee = (Employee)comboBoxEmployee.SelectedItem;
            Project project = (Project)comboBoxProject.SelectedItem;

            context.SaveChanges();
            Console.WriteLine("saveHandler");
        }

        private void cancelHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("cancelHandler");
        }
    }
}
```

and the validationRule:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WpfApplication1.validationRules
{
    public class IsNumberValidationRule : ValidationRule
    {
        private string _errorMessage;

        public string ErrorMessage
        {
            get { return _errorMessage; }
            set { _errorMessage = value; }
        }

        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value,
            CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            ValidationResult result = new ValidationResult(true, null);
            string inputString = (value ?? string.Empty).ToString();
            try
            {
                double.Parse(inputString);
            }
            catch(FormatException ex)
            {
                result = new ValidationResult(false, this.ErrorMessage);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: error pls can you put

Comment: there are no errors, it just doesn't show the error message when I enter "addfztg" in the textbox that only should contain numbers and there no red border either

Comment: So ur code not working? Its looks fine. Any error or exception?

Comment: It works but it neither shows the tooltip nor the red border at the textbox. You can add anything in the validated textbox and it doesn't show that it only allows to contain numbers.

Comment: Check the duration property defined in WorkAssignement class have getter and setter. i.e like  public string duragion {get;set;}

Comment: @Boopesh WorkAssignement is an entity object, generated from the database, so it has the getter and setter. I also think that something with my databinding is wrong, but I just don't get what it is.        public decimal duration { get; set; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was really easl. I just missed to set workassignment as my dataContext:

```
        this.DataContext = workAssignement;
```

Sarajog

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a [ViewModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) for the property bound to the textbox, textBoxDauer or create the property in your code behind, e.g Duration. In that property then do the validation like this

```
public string Duration 
{
    get { return _duration ; }
    set
    {
        _name = value;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || Int32.TryParse(value))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Dauer has to be a number..");
        }
    }
}
```

This set method is what gets called by the UpdateSourceTrigger, if an exception is thrown it will propagate up the tree and everything should work as expected.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's a window to edit an entity object that's generated from the database. I don't want to manually create objects for the validation. It's also fine by me, if I just can use the default UpdateSourceTrigger, but that didn't work either. Did you read the "Customized Validation Rules" in the tutorial?

Comment: You see do not want to update the database every time you punch in a single character. That's what UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged does. I suggest you use UpdateSourceTrigger = Explicit or LostFocus. Either way you should check the value in the property I suggested before you update the database. If it passes validation then go ahead and save it to the database.

Comment: did anyone of you det what my problem is? I just want to show the user whats wrong when he changes the value of the textbox, the way it's shown in the tutorial. the saving of the data isn't even implemented in the code I showed you. of course I will validate the data again before I save it, but I want to tell the user what's wrong before he clicks on the save button. for me it's not really important if I use LostFocus or PropertyChanged  because neither of them works in my code.